# How to include same xhtml twice in the same xhtml

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces : 4.0

All the managed beans are in view scope.

I need to include the same XHTML twice or more in a parent XHTML. Both the instances of the included xhtmls refer to the same instance of the bean.

As per my understanding, the beans are singleton. So, both the included xhtmls get the reference of the same instance of the bean.

How can I include the same xhtml more than once on the same page such that they refer to different instances of the same managed bean ?

Answer (score 0):

Your bean must implement a list of objects, for example `public List<someClass> getItems()` returning a simple list of your objects instances.

You can then access your objects instances in two ways:

1. by index `#{bean.items[0]}`, `#{bean.items[1]}`, and so on.
2. by iteration `<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.items}">`

Hope this helps.